Does Bible allow moderate life extension?
Since the dawn of humanity, our life expectancy has greatly increased. It went from 30 to 80 years in developed countries. What if we collectively manage to eradicate all diseases (like cancer for example)? Humans will still be dying from accidents and murders, just not from diseases. Does Bible allow us to cure all diseases if it is done ethically? Or should Christians be protesting against any attempts to improve our medicine (like cancer research)?
I've heard an argument that all attempts at life extension is "playing God" and most medical advances in one way or another extend our lives. I wonder if it is correct.

Some Christians might have qualms about certain life extension experiments (such as, for example, those that use stem cells) but what would make you think there'd be any Christians entirely against all medical advances??

I've heard an argument that all attempts at life extension is "playing God" and most medical advances in one way or another extend our lives. But if that's a mistaken view that's not necessarily supported by Bible, then my question is resolved.

Medicine is directly encouraged in the Bible (see 1 Tim. 5:23, for example). There may be problems in that some people turn to medicine because they're afraid of death, or they hope to achieve immortality through science, but those aren't problems with medicine or life extension per se.

@user111403 would you say that using medicine is fine for life extension even if it is life extension by 50 years?

"I've heard an argument that all attempts at life extension is "playing God" and most medical advances in one way or another extend our lives." If you could [edit] this question to add a quote of such an argument that would be a great improvement! :)

I humbly submit that attempting to hinder things that would prevent avoidable suffering, is itself a sin. Christians should support medicine, science, and technology as the stewards of Creation as well as Shepherds to other humans caring for them physically and spiritually.

"even if it is life extension by 50 years" - the point isn't how long, the point is the purpose. We're taught to value and seek to preserve life (the Mosaic Law is full of commands about preserving life). In this context, there's nothing wrong with medicine whether it prolongs life by 5 minutes or 5 centuries (not that I think we'll ever get close to that). If I'm turning to medicine as a substitute for God or as an attempt to overcome God's pattern of creation, that's a problem with me, not with medicine. Beyond that, I think Wyrsa has answered this question perfectly.

I do agree that Wyrsa's answer is great

We might get good answers here, but the website has a pretty important rule that doctrine questions be directed toward particular faith traditions so that they don't butt heads.  You're asking about "Does the Bible Allow" which is open to interpretation from different sects.

@PeterTurner While I understand the rule... this feels odd. But you're the mod.

I would like to address the historical context of the claim in the question first.
From a Bible perspective, if you view the lifespans of early humanity at the dawn of humanity it could be argued that our lifespans has greatly decreased.
Afterall, Humanity was created to be without death. (A consequence of sin) It is not that far fetched to assume that all of those early patriarchs really did live 900 years. This is something we cannot prove for certain of course, but it does deserve to be mentioned.
The lifetimes given for the antediluvian patriarchs in the Masoretic Text of the Book of Genesis are as follows. (Name, Age, Bible verse source)

Adam    930 Genesis 5:5
Seth    912 Genesis 5:8
Enosh   905 Genesis 5:11
Cainan  910 Genesis 5:14
Mahalalel   895 Genesis 5:17
Jared   962 Genesis 5:20
Enoch   365 (did not die)   Genesis 5:23
Methuselah  969 Genesis 5:27
Lamech  777 Genesis 5:31
Noah    950 Genesis 9:29

After the flood, the lifespan decreases dramatically.

Shem    600 Genesis 11:10–11
Arphaxad    438 Genesis 11:12–13
Shelah  433 Genesis 11:14–15
Eber    464 Genesis 11:16–17
Peleg   239 Genesis 11:18–19
Reu 239 Genesis 11:20–21
Serug   230 Genesis 11:22–23
Nahor   148 Genesis 11:24–25
Terah   205 Genesis 11:32
Abraham 175 Genesis 25:7

By the time of the various Psalms, the average "max" lifespan was more like what we have today roughly 80 or so years, more if we are fortunate.
As this is not the primary part of your question, I'll move on at this point.

I believe Humanity is outright commanded by God to care for God's creation (Genesis 2:15). As long as we are not intentionally harmful, if our creations benefit humanity and God's creation then it is acceptable.
The key factor here is the same as in any scientific effort. What is the ethical basis for it? For example there is nothing wrong with stem cell research, as long as you're not murdering the unborn to do it. As long as you're not "growing" humans in dishes to harvest from them. As long as you are treating the "image of God" that each human has with respect and dignity, then there is no issue. (Orthodox, Catholic, etc. church perspective)
If anything, if we can eradicate all illnesses we should do so. If we hinder this it is a sin.
We live in a time where many illnesses are (still) "unpreventable" which makes them a kind of tragedy, a suffering that cannot be helped. However as science progresses and an illness becomes preventable, it is then a "preventable suffering" which we should ethically support.
There is honestly no reason from a Biblical standpoint or theological one for us to "hinder" progress in living longer. We should not chase this goal though. That is to say, if we live our lives and naturally science and technology allow us to live longer that is fine.
But we shouldn't be like "Bryan Johnson" who wastes millions of dollars to look young. Even going so far as to "switch blood" with his son in a desperate effort to "live longer".
And ultimately there is one more thing to remember. While death is unnatural (theologically) and it is a consequence of sin. God still has allowed it to be a "mercy" of sorts. Without death, we would be trapped in the brokenness and pain of the fallen world we live in.

Death, pain and sorrow entered our lives through sin, through our disobedience. God made us for life, He planted within us the desire for immortality. God permitted death for one reason, according to the Fathers of the Church. Death, as the price of sin, is also an indication of divine mercy. According to Methodios of Olympus, God allowed death so that evil wouldn’t be immortal. Saint Gregory the Theologian says: ‘and mercy becomes punishment…’. Saint John Chrysostom says: ‘for death is such that it doesn’t annihilate the body, but does away with decay. Because the essence remains and will be resurrected in greater glory, though not for all’. Our first-born ancestors, Adam and Eve, ignoring and dismissing the divine command, tasted of the tree of the knowledge of good and evil and thus tasted death. (Hierodeacon Rafael Misiaoulis)


Yeah, I noticed that kinda afterwards. But I think the question is not actually about life expectancy or lifespan. It is about should christians be pro or against medical science? And the answer is clearly "pro medical science"

The link provided starts by confining its statistics to a current-day average for the United States: "it was 78 years (75 years for males and 80 years for females)."
That in no way mitigates against the biblical statement, that after Abraham's era, it would drop to 70 years, or 80 for persons stronger than others. See Psalm 90:10.
Then it jumps to a Paleolithic era, and pre-history, to assume certain ages pertained to human skeletons. Being charitable, this amounts to nothing more than an educated guess. Yet, even if we give the benefit of the doubt and agree that lots of human skeletons indicate very short life-spans, that has always been the case throughout all of human existence, mainly due to famines, floods, wars, and very high rates of infant mortality. If a study could be done of two countries today, where wars rage, the average life-expectancy might be way below 50 years. And what about the average life-expectancy for the whole nation of Japan, for the entire 20th century? Hiroshima and Nagasaki, anyone?
Now, the question may confine itself to 'normal' conditions where there is no war, fire, flood, famine etc, but that actually is a rare condition. Only affluent Westerners today might insist that the 'average' lifespan is increasing, and that medical improvements could make an exponential leap in the not too distant future. With all due respect to medical professionals and scientists, they cannot do a thing to cut out fire, flood, famine and war. To offer stats. that ignore the effect of all that on average human lifespans is to skew the stats.
However, this hypothetical question about "What if..." and whether "the Bible allows moderate life extension", is disallowed on this site. It is wide open to opinions and goes outside the scope of doctrine promoted by specific Christian groups. Very simply, the Bible upholds the sanctity of human life, and that God requires those who shed human blood to forfeit their own lives. The preservation of life is seen throughout the entire Bible, with God's acts of salvation and mercy. Supremely, God has provided the only means to live eternally, and will grant that to those putting faith in his gracious provision.
Finally, medical and scientific professionals devoted to saving and prolonging human life are full of Christians from every group you care to mention. That, in itself, answers your question.

Good point, Bible is kinda a book about getting eternal life. :)

"Hiroshima and Nagasaki, anyone?" — They were extremely spectacular events, but statistically not highly significant. Around 200,000 there, vs. the Japanese government's estimate of 3.1 million for the entire war, so they account for only about 6–7%. (Using words like "only" and "significant" doesn't feel right here.) ¶ C.S. Sentinal says "Sentinels of June 18, 1990, and of January 7, 1991, tell of two doctors' giving up their profession to become Christian Scientists.".

@RayButterworth Indeed, stats. for war deaths may seem small compared to other causes of death, but my point is really to protest that such figures, plus stats. for death by fire, flood and famine are shoved aside by those claiming "we are now living much longer, on average!" Some 'average' that ignores many causes of death! Your comments appreciated.

“There are three kinds of lies: lies, damned lies, and statistics.”  This quote by Courtney is the published version of a speech on proportional representation that was given in August 1895 in New York State, which may help explain how Mark Twain came to know the phrase. Beware politicians and media sources who dish out statistics as if they were unquestionable facts!
